# Return nothing from Action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC form where the user can set criteria, hit the submit button to post, and a file is dynamically generated and returned:

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Certificates.pdf");
return File(merged.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
```

This works well because it downloads the file and leave the original form untouched so the user can easily modify the criteria and submit again. In same cases there will be no file to return and I'd like to retain the form's state. How can I do this? I can't redirect back to itself because there's been action submitted already. I can't check client-side before submitting because the logic is server side. Basically I just need to cancel the post.

Answer (score 2):

this should do the trick:

```
return new EmptyResult();
```

Comment: This is returning a blank page - I want to see the original form.

Comment: oh, my bad, so yeah, then the answer by @WannaCSharp is the right one

Comment: Crud, was hoping for a quick and dirty fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the View with the model and it will retain the form state.

```
if (file == null) 
{
    return View(model);
}
```